# Stoping a for loop in java while looping through an Arraylist?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm writting a part of a validation for a login system for a school project.
I'm trying to loop through an ArrayList containing the members. It works with only one object in the ArrayList but as soon as there is more than one to for loop will keep going.

```
public void confirmation(TextField username, PasswordField password) throws NameException {
    data.loadDatabase();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.LoginMembers.size(); i++) {
        if (username.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getUsername())) {
            this.a = true;
            System.out.println("Username right");

            if (password.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getPassword())) {
                this.b = true;
                System.out.println("Password right");
                this.user = data.LoginMembers.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Password wrong")
                this.a = false;
                throw new NameException();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username wrong");
            this.a = false;
            throw new NameException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you get infinit loop ?

Comment: This would be much more readable if you used a for-each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, as soon as you validate the user password u want to quit from the loop then just add a break like this:

```
public void confirmation(TextField username, PasswordField password) throws NameException
{
data.loadDatabase();
for(int i = 0; i < data.LoginMembers.size(); i++)
{
    if(username.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getUsername()))
    {
            this.a = true;
            System.out.println("Username right");

            if(password.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getPassword()))
            {
                this.b = true;
                System.out.println("Password right");
                this.user = data.LoginMembers.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Password wrong");
                this.a = false;
                throw new NameException();
            }
    } 

    else
    {
            System.out.println("Username wrong");
            this.a = false;
            throw new NameException();
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break;` to stop any loop

Answer (score 0):

In the block of code where the password is right (or wherever else you need it) you can add the line:

```
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the purpose of the method enough,  then I recommend following changes:

- if you find a user/password match then just exit the method (return)
- iterate over all users in the database before throwing an exception.  Right now you will fail if you have two users and the entered user/pass combination is for the second one

Here the sample modification:

```
public void confirmation(TextField username, PasswordField password) throws NameException {
    data.loadDatabase();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.LoginMembers.size(); i++) {
        if (username.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getUsername())) {
            this.a = true;
            System.out.println("Username right");

            if (password.getText().equals(data.LoginMembers.get(i).getPassword())) {
                this.b = true;
                System.out.println("Password right");
                this.user = data.LoginMembers.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName().toString();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Username or password wrong");
    this.a = false;
    throw new NameException();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i've been fighting! is there anyway i can get you to elaborate on your two changes? i'm quite a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**break**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statement. In addition, you can break loops by label.

```
search:
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == searchfor) {
                break search;
            }
        }
    }
```

If condition is true, both loops will be terminated.